# Failed to prepare CRTC for page flipping, disabling TearFree

Tags: xorg, xrandr, gdm, tearing, thunderbolt

I have the following issue: My laptop is suspended and connected via Thunderbolt to by Docking Station. When I press a key to wake up the laptop the external monitor (connected via the dock) turns on and everything looks fine. Then, after a few seconds, it turns shortly black and then back on again, but this time I have screen tearing. I found the following messages in the log:

```
Mär 31 11:10:22 findus kernel: [drm:drm_dp_mst_dpcd_read [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* mstb 000000004c46c010 port 3: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus systemd[1]: Starting autorandr execution hook...
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2595]: (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1-2
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2595]: (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1-2
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus dunst[3923]: CRITICAL: Get monitors reported 0 monitors. Falling back to single monitor mode.
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2595]: (EE) intel(0): Failed to prepare CRTC for page flipping, disabling TearFree
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2728]: [../i3bar/src/xcb.c:1042] ERROR: PropertyNotify received for unknown window 00800874
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2728]: [../i3bar/src/xcb.c:1042] ERROR: PropertyNotify received for unknown window 00e0038d
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2595]: (II) intel(0): switch to mode 2560x1440@60.0 on DP1-2 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus terminator[19558]: gdk_event_set_source_device: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus terminator[19558]: gdk_device_get_source: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus terminator[19558]: gdk_event_set_source_device: assertion 'GDK_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus autorandr[292558]: autorandr running as user cmosig (started from batch instance)
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus autorandr[292558]: home (detected)
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus autorandr[292558]: beamer
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus autorandr[292558]: laptop
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2728]: [../i3bar/src/xcb.c:1042] ERROR: PropertyNotify received for unknown window 00e0039e
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2728]: [../i3bar/src/xcb.c:1042] ERROR: PropertyNotify received for unknown window 0080088f
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2728]: [../i3bar/src/xcb.c:864] ERROR: Error getting _XEMBED_INFO property: error_code 3
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus autorandr[292553]: Running autorandr as cmosig for display :0
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus systemd[1]: autorandr.service: Succeeded.
Mär 31 11:10:26 findus systemd[1]: Finished autorandr execution hook.
Mär 31 11:10:32 findus kernel: [drm:drm_dp_mst_dpcd_read [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* mstb 000000004c46c010 port 1: DPCD read on addr 0x4b0 for 1 bytes NAKed
```

One of the lines reads "Disabling TearFree", so it's probably somehow related to that. Does anyone have an idea how I can troubleshoot this? Is this a timing issue of autorandr? Is there any additional information I can provide that would help?

(I can fix the tearing by simply switching back and forth once between different autorandr configurations. But this is really annoying...)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Option "TripleBuffer" "true"` to the intel driver config file `20-intel.conf` seemed to fix the issue.

EDIT: this seemed to not fully fix the issue. It helped, but I am still regularly experiencing screen tearing after suspending my system.